# Laravel : Search Query filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have `searchDetails` array in my search. I have done all other search and get data on filter, Problem is that when i search with `stone_min, stone_max` I get data if there is only one `searchDetails` array, if there is two data it is return null. How can i do this ? I want search with `stone_min, stone_max` for particular `product_id`.

what i try :

Example for data to search :

```
{

  "limit": 1000,
  "offset":0,
  "user_id": "",
  "min_price": "",
  "max_price": "",
  "searchDetails": [
    {
      "product_id": "1", 
      "attributeId": [], 
      "is_exclude": "no",
      "stone_min": "5",
      "stone_max": "15"
    },
     {
      "product_id": "2", 
      "attributeId": [], 
      "is_exclude": "no",
      "stone_min": "100",
      "stone_max": "500"
    }
  ]
}
```

My query for getting all data

```
  $searchablePost     = Post::with(['product','postattribute.attribute.category','user.userDetails'])
        ->whereIn('product_id', $userApprovalProductIDs)
        ->where('status', 'Active')
        ->whereIn('demand_or_supply', $demand_or_supply);
```

Search for min-max stone :

```
 if (count($searchDetails) > 0) {
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($searchDetails as $value) {
                if (strtolower(trim($value['is_exclude'])) == "no") {
                        $searchablePost =  $searchablePost->where(function ($query) use ($value)  {
                            if ($value['stone_min'] && $value['stone_max']) {
                                if (isset($j) && $j == 0){
                                    $query->where('stone_min', '>=', $value['stone_min'])->where('stone_max', '<=', $value['stone_max'])->where("product_id", (int)$value['product_id']);
                                } else {
                                    $query->where('stone_min', '>=', $value['stone_min'])->where('stone_max', '<=', $value['stone_max'])->where("product_id", (int)$value['product_id']);
                                }
                            }
                        });
               }
            }
        }
       $searchedPost = $searchablePost->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi  i want to search with `stone_min, stone_max` value for particular `product_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search between `stone_min` and `stone_max` for particualar product then do:

```
$request = json_decode($request->searchDetails, true);

$stoneMinMax = collect($request)->pluck('stone_min', 'stone_max');

Product::where(function($q) use($productId) ($stoneMinMax){
   $q->where('product_id', $productId)
     ->whereBetween('stone_column', $stoneMinMax->toArray());
})->get();
```